# Allow specific application to appear above "TopMost" Form

Tags: c#

I'm building a small program to try to help lockdown thin client terminals. I've use the TopMost property to prevent users from getting to anything behind my software, but what I'm wondering is if it's possible to allow specific applications 'through' that.

For example, say they were allowed to open Word. My software can invoke msword.exe (Which is fine) but it'll open underneath the application. This is as expected and desired behaviour for everything, apart from msword.exe in this example. So, is there a way to allow the msword.exe process to appear above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "No." If there was such a mechanism, it would lead to an escalating arms race where everyone uses the highest "level" to get on top of everyone else.

The best way to restrict access in Windows is to use the Security features already built in. You can change file access on a per-user basis.

Comment: That's fine and does make sense. I'll find some kind of alternative route!